# how to import build-in tasks with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to import task with Powershell and getting this error
BTW using import in Task Scheduler is working fine

CMDLINE:
PS C:\windows\system32> **Register-ScheduledTask -Xml "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\TextServicesFramework\MsCtfMonitor" -TaskName "MsCtfMonitor"**

Error:
Register-ScheduledTask : **The task XML is malformed.
(1,2)::ERROR: incorrect document syntax**
At line:1 char:1

- Register-ScheduledTask -Xml "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Wind ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004131a,Register-ScheduledTask
  ```

edit another solution that might help in other cases:
powershell -command "& { Register-ScheduledTask -Xml ([System.Io.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\TextServicesFramework\MsCtfMonitor')) -TaskName 'MsCtfMonitor' }"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the actual text of the xml, rather than just the file path:

```
Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content ("C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\TextServicesFramework\MsCtfMonitor") | Out-String ) -TaskName "MsCtfMonitor"
```